# How to make a string search features in any conditions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, search

I had a struggle when i made a search feature for my project. My search feature only could search depend on my input field which is case sensitive.

This is my search feature result for example:

we will search a data and the title of data is "Harry Potter"

if i search with "Harry Potter",the return is true

But,

if i search with "harry potter",the return is false

how should i do to solve it?

Comment: Post your code please, it could be something as simple as checking against lowercase, but no idea how you're implementing this.

Comment: Are you looking for .ignoreCase or .toUpperCase ? Ignores the caps